# Selenium WebDriver get text inside of a span

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract the `"This is our address"` text inside of a span where HTML code are as follows:

```
<div id="comp-kvi6khho" class="2hij5_3bcaz">
<p class="font_8">
<span style="letter-spacing:normal;">
<span class="color_11">This is our address</span>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("color_11")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#comp-kvi6khho > p:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/section[9]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/p/span/span")).getAttribute("InnerHTML");
```

so far. But all of them I get `Unable to locate element` error.
How can I extract the text inside of most inner span class?

Comment: Try the JavascriptExecutorof Selenium WebDriver 
```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript(Script);
```
Here the Script is something like for your case: "document.getElementsByClassName("color_11").value"

Comment: Nope. not working. Also I am using Java, not JS. Btw what should I do if that element is inside an iframe? Should I switch to it and then locate element itself? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I was not aware of the existence of iframes. The element I was looking for is inside of an iframe. First, I had to locate the iframe, then switch to it and then I located the element itself.

The code I used for that is below:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe").findElement(By.cssSelector("#comp-kvi6khho > p:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")).getText();
```